# Dull Ember in Scholar of the First Sin

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

I'm looking for the Dull Ember, so that I can imbue my stuff. Everywhere I've read puts its location in the Lost Bastille, in the room the giant crow drops you off at after you beat the pursuer in the Forest of Fallen Giants, but I've got no idea where that is, and my initial reaction to seeing the Pursuer appear was to go back down the ladder and hope he went away(and he did) so I can't actually get there by that means.

How do I get to the room with the Dull Ember?

Comment: Which version are you playing? I'm asking this because the PS3 version of Scholar of the First Sin has the items with the same location as the normal version. 
I believe that the stuff you've read is for SofS in the new consoles or PC version. The wikis that you can find on the internet state that "SofS" location is "x". But this does not apply to PS3 or X360 version.
In my case, the PS3 version, the dull ember is in the Iron Keep.

Comment: I'm playing the PC version, through steam.

Comment: Ok, sorry.
A fast search on the wiki says that after the fight with the Pursuer you will go to The Lost Bastille first bonfire where you have the Dull Ember inside a chest.
I believe (by my PS3 version experience) that the fight with the pursuer you are talking about is the first one, optional fight in which he drops from an eagle. You have the option to flee.
Later on the game, you will fight him again, in the Forest of the Fallen giants, too. And here, when you defeat him, you interact with a bird's nest, and you are transported to the Lost Bastille first bonfire.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Put that up as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast search on the wiki ([here](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Dull+Ember)) says that after the fight with the Pursuer you will go to The Lost Bastille first bonfire where you have the Dull Ember inside a chest.

I believe (by my PS3 version experience) that the fight with the pursuer you are talking about is the first one, optional fight in which he drops from an eagle. You have the option to flee.

Later on the game, you will fight him again, in the Forest of the Fallen giants, too. And here, when you defeat him, you interact with a bird's nest, and you are transported to the Lost Bastille first bonfire.